# How to fill array in C++?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int a = [];
    int b = 10;
    std::fill(a);
    cout<<a<<endl;
}
```

I have an array "a" and want to fill it with an integer "b". As I remember in python its simply uses apppend, does someone know solution?

Comment: Decide size of the array `a` first, or use `std::vector`.

Comment: `int a = [];` is not valid C++.

Comment: C++ is not Python.

Comment: Seems like declaring `a` as a `std:array` would let you use `std::array::fill()` -- https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/fill

Comment: The `std::fill` takes 3 parameters:  starting address, one past end, and fill value.

Answer (score 4):

Here one solution how to use your array header.

```
int b = 10;
std::array<int, 3> a;
std::fill(begin(a), end(a), b);
```

Answer (score 4):

> I have an array "a"
>
> ```
> int a = [];
> ```

What you have is a syntax error.

> As I remember in python its simply uses apppend

A major difference between a C++ array and python list is that the size of C++ array cannot change, and thus nothing can be appended into it.

> How to fill array in C++?

There is indeed a standard algorithm for this purpose:

```
int a[4];
int b = 10;
std::fill_n(a, std::size(a), b);
```

Answer (score 1):

Decide the size for a, as it is an array not a list. For example:

```
int a[10];
```

Then use index values to fill in the array like:

```
a[0] = 1;
a[1] = 4;
```

etc.

If you want a dynamic array use std::vector instead

Here is how its done with vectors:

```
std::vector<int> myvector;
int myint = 3;

myvector.push_back (myint);
```

Comment: Why not using std:array if he included it?

Comment: @akirahinoshiro ok I edited my answer to include how its done with vectors

Comment: Author asked about "how to fill" an array, so I guess it is worth mentioning `std::fill(std::begin(a), std::end(a), some_value);`

Comment: @pptaszni I thought he was talking about appending integers to the array

Comment: The problem with this solution of 'int a[10]' what happens if you access the 11th member of your array?

Answer (score 0):

Following zohaib's answer:
If your array is of fixed length:
You can use the array's 'fill' member function like this:
a.fill(b);
If your array can change it's size you can use the std's fill function like this:
std::fill(a.begin(), a.end(),  b);

Comment: arrays are always of fixed size and `a.fill(b);` and `std::fill(a.begin(),a.end(),b)` are doing the same