# Populating a buffer in C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to populate this entire buffer that I created with the numerical value 9.
This buffer is suppose to be 1024 MB

I know I can create the buffer like this.

```
LPVOID buffer = VirtualAlloc(nullptr,(1 * 1024 * 1024) * 1024, MEM_COMMIT,PAGE_READWRITE);
```

My question is how can I populate this buffer. Basically what I am looking for is code on how I can iterate over this buffer and insert value into it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [c++ - How to use <random> to fill std::array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41152968/c-how-to-use-random-to-fill-stdarray)

Comment: duplicate for populating with a single byte value: [How to fill array in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63035170/995714)

Comment: Better define it as `LPBYTE`.

Comment: "Populating a buffer" means, I guess, putting values in the buffer. To answer this question you need to tell us what type are these values and what are the values you want to put. Because of the `1` it looks are size of the type is one, so probably `char`? or your value type has size `1024`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard C Library has also memory functions in the string header file.

```
#include <string>

memset(buffer, 9, (1 * 1024 * 1024) * 1024));
```

or just use the for loop and do explicit type casts. You can do everything you want with memory in C++

```
uint8_t* buffer_as_int = static_cast<uint8_t*>(buffer);
for(size_t i=0,sz=(1024*1024*1024); i<sz; i++) {
   *buffer_as_int = random_byte();
}
```

You can cast it to whatever type you want, then you change the for loop to an iterator that moves from one pointer to the next

```
struct Foo { int hello; bool world; };  // 5 bytes aligned to 8 

Foo initial_foo;
initial_foo.hello = 666; 
initial_foo.world = no;

LPVOID end_of_buffer = static_cast<uint8_t*>(buffer) + (1024*1024*1024);
while(buffer < end_of_buffer) {
   *static_cast<Foo*>(buffer) = initial_foo;
   buffer = static_cast<uint8_t*>(buffer) + sizeof(foo);
}
```

If you understand this example you learned that you can cast everything from and to void easily and do pointer arithmetic on it, because with the addition of a little type checking, a pointer is nothing else than an integer number representing the address of a starting byte in the RAM.

Short, amazing and many say ugly, but C programmers love to do this. And in every heart of a C++ programmer is a little hidden C programmer who want to come out and do dirty things from m time to time.

Comment: Thanks. is there a way for me to loop over this buffer so I can insert random values into this ? instead of just the value 9 ?

Comment: @JamesFranco, isn't for loop not enough.

Comment: @JamesFranco
You can maybe do memset(buffer + offset, data, size)
Using the offset and size in your loop.

Comment: in C++ it's better to use `std::fill`. And there are many better/faster ways to populate a random array like `std::random_device` or `std::generate`

Comment: @JamesFranco why do you ask about filling 9 in the question but and filling with random bytes in the comment? They are completely different questions

Comment: Thanks for this great answer. I wish I could get better at C

Answer (score 1):

Since the question is tagged C++, here's an **important note on filling uninitialized memory**. When in need to create objects in a range that was created without calling constructors, you need to use [`std::uninitialized_fill`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/uninitialized_fill). This algorithm essentially **calls placement new on the "buffer slots" to first enforce a constructor call on the buffer elements**. This process is very important in cases where the buffer was created by calling e.g. `malloc` that is unaware of constructors and performs both steps of constructing and initializing. You can ignore this when initializing trivial types.

---

When there's a specific value you want to populate with, use [`std::fill`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill).

```
std::fill(buffer, buffer + buffer_sz, value);
```

When in need to create elements according to some policy use [`std::generate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate):

```
std::generate(buffer, buffer + buffer_sz, [] { 
  /* generate some value */ 
} );
```

Both solutions assume your buffer is strongly typed, i.e. `++buffer` will point to the next element in the range. For `void*` buffers this means you have to cast the iterator to the appropriate type, e.g. :

```
std::fill(
  static_cast<int*>(buffer), // Creates a strongly typed iterator
  static_cast<int*>(buffer + buffer_size), 
  value);
```

That been said, note that for specific uses the standard library offers specialized algorithms, e.g. theres `std::iota` if you want to fill a range with sequence.